# Clojure.data.xml: append XML Element

Tags: clojure

My Goal is to append Child Elements under another XML Element (the parent). Lets say under `<Books>`.

```
(def bookshelf
  (xml/element :books {}))
```

So i would like to create `<Book>` Elements dynamically and append to  as Long as they are created one After the other.

Does anyone  have a clue how to do this using the lib `clojure.data.xml`?

Thx in advance. 
Horace

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Quick Start Examples of their library you can do it as follows:

```
(let [tags (element :foo {:foo-attr "foo value"}
             (element :bar {:bar-attr "bar value"}
               (element :baz {} "The baz value")))]
  (with-open [out-file (java.io.FileWriter. "/tmp/foo.xml")]
    (emit tags out-file)))
```

Gives you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <foo foo-attr="foo value">
     <bar bar-attr="bar value">
       <baz>
         The baz value
       </baz>
     </bar>
    </foo>
```